# When to use Objective-C class methods vs C functions

Tags: objective-c, c, function, objective-c-category

### My problem

I'm trying to come up with an appropriate pattern. Let's imagine I want to create a piece of code I can provide with color and size and receive a UIImage of that size filled with that color. I can do it in many different ways, but I think these two would be the most common.

- Objective-C class method

I can create a UIImage category with a class method like

```
+ (UIImage *)bch_imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color size:(CGSize)size;
```

- C function

I can make a simple C function

```
UIImage *BCHImageWithColorAndSize(UIColor *color, CGSize size);
```

And of course both would work perfectly fine.

Now I know key differences between these two approaches, but I cannot pin point any of those differences agains or in favor of any approach.

### Apple's pattern

I tried to lookup patterns in Apple's frameworks and just got even more confused. We have for example:

`NSString *NSStringFromCGPoint(CGPoint point);`

`CGPoint CGPointFromString(NSString *string);`

which are functions. But then again there are NSValue's class and instance methods:

`+ (NSValue *)valueWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point;`

`- (CGPoint)CGPointValue;`

I'll greatly appreciate any insight, thoughts, or ideas you might have.

Comment: One thing to consider... class methods can be dynamically determined at runtime by their name and use of ObjC's reflection abilities, while a C function cannot. This provides extra flexibility in specialized cases. There is also some amount of ObcJ runtime-induced overhead for calling methods that calling a C function does not need to perform.

Comment: @mah Yes, performance-wise functions should be a bit faster, yet less flexible than methods. I did think about that, and while performance argument is surely true, it's not crucial in this case. While flexibility, I'm not sure, maybe in the future. Another thing worth mentioning, is that class methods open the possibility to return a potential subclass object (e.g. BCHImage) if I ever intended, while the function would remain UIImage forever. But again, that is not the case for me, as I do not expect to subclass UIImage ever.

Comment: @MikeD Yes, I did look into that topic before, but apart from technical details I could not find any information on which method is actually better in certain cases. Perhaps this information is there, but I just can't put it together.

Comment: @BartekChlebek a C function could also return a subclass... just declare the return type of the function to be `id`. Recently I designed a pattern where a dylib contains a single exported C function, and an internal class. I defined the C function to return a `id<MyProtocol>` where the object it returns are guaranteed to serve the defined protocol. This allowed clients to link to the library and call its only entry point as an object allocator.

Comment: I think key term is **better**. In your use case, and possible future use cases, what appears to be the best tool for your task? And how easy will it be for you maintain and update your code going forward. I am not sure there is clear cut **better** option between the two.

Comment: @mah Is it really possible? Unless I make the function take the desired class as a parameter and work with that, there is no way to do that I am familiar with. I cannot override the function afaik.

Comment: @MikeD I'm afraid you're right and there is no golden rule. I try to avoid mixing C with ObjC and keep the interfaces clean, but every once in a while I bump against such dilemmas. Thanks :) If you come up with anything, I'll gladly hear you out.

Comment: @BartekChlebek there's no overriding necessary with what I'm describing... the `id` type is kind of like saying `void *` in that you're defining something (it's an _object_) but not much (not what type of object). It's definitely possible, as in my case I needed my caller to be unaware of the object type and this made it work easily. The ObjC runtime helps, since you don't have to know at compile time if methods you call on the object exist (an exception is thrown if they don't, and you can check at runtime also).